# Why change of element order in an array in *ngFor="let x of xs" wouldn't trigger component onChanges?

Tags: angular

I have a parent component:

```
<div *ngFor="let slice of slices">
    <my-slice [slice]="slice">
</div>
```

and child component:

```
export class SliceComponent implements OnChanges {
    @Input()
    slice: Slice;
    ...
}
```

If I run the following code in the parent component, the children components won't get updated, though the view order does change.

```
    let slice = this.slices[0];
    this.slices[0] = this.slices[1];
    this.slices[1] = slice;
```

Additionally, if I add the following

```
<div *ngFor="let slice of slices; let i=index">
    <my-slice [slice]="slice" [sliceOrder]="i">
</div>
```

Now `onChanges` would get fired with changes set to `sliceOrder` instead of `slice`.

How does angular2 choose what is changed in component input property? Why in this case it is `sliceOrder` that gets changed, not `slice`?

Answer (score 0):

`*ngFor` checks array content to know when to update but Angular2 change detection doesn't check array or object content. It only checks object identity.

As workarounds

- you can create a copy of the array to get a new identity `this.arr = this.arr.slice()`
- you can implement `ngDoCheck` and check for content changes yourself, for example using an `IterableDiffers` provided by Angular. See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/DoCheck-class.html